# Why the value changes when I assign it to a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+---------+-------------+
|   id    |    ban      |
+---------+-------------+
| int(11) |   BIT(11)   |
+---------+-------------+
| 1       | 01111111000 |
| 2       | 01111111111 |
| 3       | 00000000001 |
+---------+-------------+
```

As you see, the value of `ban` column is a binary number *(its datatype is `BIT(11)`)*. and when I select it, the value is still a binary number, like this:

```
SELECT ban FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;
-- output: 01111111000
```

But when I assign it to a variable, surprisingly the value changes, like this:

```
SELECT ban INTO @ban FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;
SELECT @ban;
-- output: 1016
```

Well what happens when I set `01111111000` into `@ban`? Why it will be changed *(`1016`)*?

---

You know? In reality, each digit *(bit)* of that 11-bit number *(`01111111000`)* refers to something. For example, the second bit determines user's limitation on voting. I mean it the first digit (right to left) is `1`, it means the user can vote, if it is `0` it means the user is banned for voting.

Anyway, I don't need to get a decimal like this `1016`. I need to assign and keep exactly that 11-bit number to `@ban` variable. Because I need to check it like this:

```
IF ( IFNULL((@ban & b'10' > 0), 0) < 1 ) THEN
 -- user can vote
ELSE 
-- user cannot vote
ENDIF;
```

So there is different action for each digit. That's why I don't want a 10-based number like `1016`. I want a bit-based number like this `01111111000` in that variable.

To make it more clear, here is the task of third digit:

```
IF ( IFNULL((@ban & b'100' > 0), 0) < 1 ) THEN
 -- user can flag
ELSE 
-- user cannot flag
ENDIF;
```

See? the third digit *(of that 11-bit number)* determines user's flagging ability *(limitation)*.

---

Ok, in conclusion, how can I assign a bit value to a variable without converting its datatype *(which seems converting will be happened automatically, so how can I avoid that)*?

Comment: `1016` is decimal representation of binary `01111111000`. You can use it in bit operation the same way as you use binary.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev interesting .. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different representations of the same number, one in base 2 and base 10.

You can still use the bits of 1016 as flags.

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/76391)

Comment: Do you mean `1016 & b'10'` and `01111111000 & b'10'` are identical? I mean will both of them treat the same?

Comment: Yes the same. See linked fiddle.